# Google Cloud Platform firewall allow os update

Tags: ubuntu, security, firewall, google-cloud-platform

I have a Virtual Machine running inside Google Cloud. The VM running ubuntu v16. The machine is running behind firewall. The traffic to this machine is restricted - no outgoing traffic allowed from this machine to the internet.

The problem is that I want to expose the machine to system updates.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

Which running automatically as background task.

Is this possible to allow OS updates egress traffic only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decide if you will be managing a local repo of updates. Which would allow for more control of both when updates happen and what gets Internet access.

You probably want to use GCP's mirror, `us-central1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com`  (replace us-central1 with your region).

Configure firewall to allow egress from the downloading systems. IPs and not names, but a handful of IP addresses that may change isn't too bad even if you want to be super-specific.

If you have zero Internet access, consider something like a cloud NAT. Unfortunately, GCP doesn't have the equivalent to AWS's IPv6 egress only gateways.